# Plotting Logistic Regression from Linear Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, logistic-regression

I have a working Linear Regression algorithm and can use it to graph, but I cannot figure out how to graph Logistic Regression using the sigmoid transformation.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
m = 0
c = 0

L = 0.0001  # The learning Rate
epochs = 1000  # The number of iterations to perform gradient descent

n = float(len(X)) # Number of elements in X

#performing gradient descent
for i in range(epochs):
    Y_pred = m*X + c  # The current predicted value of Y
    D_m = (-2/n) * sum(X * (Y - Y_pred))  # Derivative wrt m
    D_c = (-2/n) * sum(Y - Y_pred)  # Derivative wrt c
    m = (m - L * D_m)  # Update m
    c = (c - L * D_c)  # Update c
    
print (m, c)

# Making predictions
Sx = 1 / (1+(np.exp(-Y_pred)))


plt.scatter(df.x1, df.x2, c=df.y, cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(['red','blue']))
plt.plot([min(X), max(X)], [min(Y_pred), max(Y_pred)])  # regression line
plt.show()
```

The program prints m as approximately 0.6985, and c as 0.9674.

And here's a screenshot of the plot when using Linear Regression:
[Linear Regression Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCEga.png)

Pretending for a moment this is regression problem, this would appear to be correct output. But, since linear regression is not an appropriate fit for this kind of dataset, (I am attempting to classify two sets, red and blue) when I change the graph to show Sx I get what appears to be a straight line that starts at 0 and approaches 1 as it reaches the right side of the graph. This makes sense to me, since the classes are meant to change that way (the reds are class 0 centered around the left and the blues are class 1 on the right). However, the scikit-learn LogisticRegression implementation allows me to output a much better looking graph, like this:

[Scikit-Learn LogisticRegression Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAH0e.png)

How can I create a similar graph when the outputs of the sigmoid function are between 0 and 1?

Comment: This is essentially a contour plot, because you want to plot the line where f(x, y) = 0.5. This could be helpful: https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.04-density-and-contour-plots.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the way you have calculated the gradients for logistic regression. Here is what I did. ref: https://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logistic_regression.html

The logistic regression line is as follows, given we have 2 features X1 and X2,

log reg = 1 / (1 + e(-z))

z = w0 + w1.x1 + w2.x2 (w0 is like c, w1 is like m1 and w2 is m2)

so using z

we need to get the values of x1 if we use x2 and vice versa

so: Lets say we will create line for x2, this is found with the equation

0 = w0 + w1.x1 + w2.x2

we use the above because

1 / (1 + e(-z)) = 0.5

2 = (1 + e(-z))

1 = e(-z)

ln(1) = ln(e(-z))

0 = -z

z = 0

0 = w0 + w1.x1 + w2.x2

===============================

so,

x2 = (-w0 -w1.x1) / w2

plug in values for x1, and we get x2 values.

These values form the decision boundary.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np

from sklearn.datasets import *
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale

X,Y = make_blobs(n_samples = 20,n_features=2,centers=2,random_state=75,cluster_std = 5)
X = minmax_scale(X)
X = np.hstack([np.ones(len(X)).reshape(-1,1), X])

B = np.array([1,1,1]) #weights

L = 0.01  # The learning Rate
epochs = 5000  # The number of iterations to perform gradient descent


N = len(X) #number of records

for i in range(epochs):

    Y_pred = np.dot(X, B) #prediction

    h = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-Y_pred)) # sigmoid

    Cost = (-np.multiply(Y,np.log(h))) - np.multiply((1-Y),np.log(1 - h)) 

    J = np.mean(Cost) #cost to minimize // to print out

    gradient = np.dot(X.T,  h - Y)

    gradient = gradient / N

    gradient = gradient * L

    B  = B - gradient #update weights
    
    #print ("cost = ", J)

decision_boundary = (-B[1] * (np.arange(100) / 100) - B[0]) / B[2]

plt.scatter(X[:,1],X[:,2], c = Y)
plt.plot(np.arange(100) / 100, decision_boundary)
put.show()
```